# How can I make nrepl-ritz-jack-in work remotely over TRAMP / Emacs

Tags: clojure, nrepl

### What I want:

I have a clojure program on a remote site, let's call it `mccarthy`.
What I want to do is connect to a `nrepl-ritz` from my laptop, preferably using `nrepl-ritz-jack-in`.  The jack in works fine for a local program, but doesn't seem to connect to a remote program.

### Attempt 1

<kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>C-f</kbd> on `/mccarthy:code/program/project.clj`

`(require 'nrepl-ritz)`

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `nrepl-ritz-jack-in`

### Result

Emacs appears to hang.  If I go to the `*nrepl-server*` buffer, I see this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at org.flatland.drip.Main.invoke(Main.java:117)
    at org.flatland.drip.Main.start(Main.java:88)
    at org.flatland.drip.Main.main(Main.java:64)
Caused by: java.lang.AssertionError: Assert failed: project
    at leiningen.ritz_nrepl$start_jpda_server.invoke(ritz_nrepl.clj:23)
    at leiningen.ritz_nrepl$ritz_nrepl.doInvoke(ritz_nrepl.clj:95)
```

(and tons of other lines, too...)

I am using `drip` on my laptop, but not on `mccarthy`, so clearly `nrepl-ritz-jack-in` is not detecting that it's a remote file.  Regular old `nrepl-jack-in` will work as expected in this case, however.

### Attempt 2

I also tried starting an `nrepl-ritz` using `lein` on `mccarthy`:

```
mattox@mccarthy$ lein ritz-nrepl
nREPL server started on port 42874
```

From my laptop I forward a port so local `42874` connects to `42874` on `mccarthy`:

```
ssh -L 42874:localhost:42874 -N mccarthy
```

Then, from my local Emacs:

```
(require 'nrepl-ritz)
```

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `nrepl`

Host: `127.0.0.1`

Port: `42874`

This gives me a connection:

```
; nREPL 0.1.7-preview
user>
```

So to test it out, I run

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `nrepl-ritz-threads`

It gives me a nice table of threads.

<kbd>M-x</kbd> `nrepl-ritz-break-on-exception`

```
user> (/ 1 0)
```

### Result

This hangs, but sometimes shows a hidden debugging buffer with some restarts available.  If I tell it to pass the exception back to the program, it never gives control back to the REPL.

I've done plenty of searches but have not been able to get anything more specific than "make sure lein is on your path".  (And I did do that, on both machines...)  Thanks for reading a (I hope not too) long question!

---

This question was originally [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15330810/how-can-i-make-nrepl-ritz-jack-in-work-remotely-over-tramp-emacs) by [MattoxBeckman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10354/mattoxbeckman), but has yet to be answered.